# Basic URL rewrite with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I would like to rewrite the URL of one of my pages from

```
http://www.mydomain.com/some/application/page.html
```

to

```
http://www.mydomain.com/apply
```

I believe this code will work. But in 301 redirects, you often see [R=301,L] or some version of that appended to the end of the rewrite rule - is the code below the best way to perform the redirection and will Google understand it?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /some/application/page.html?=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Do you mean to say you want use `http://www.mydomain.com/apply` for the users? If yes, the URL's should interchange in the above question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do this:

The URL that your users see (even google):

```
http://www.mydomain.com/apply
```

to

```
http://www.mydomain.com/some/application/page.html
```

the internal(actual) URL.

then I would suggest you to go this:

```
RewriteEngine On

#condition to redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?apply/?$
RewriteRule ^/?apply/?$ /some/application/page.html [L]
```

The flag `[L]` ( [Flag L  <sup>docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) ) signifies RewriteEngine to stop rewriting any rules further. This will not perform a permanent redirection. 
You don't need a `[R=301]` flag here. 301 is for permanent redirection. Use the short URL everywhere.

Comment: For SEO reasons I'd like to use mod_rewrite and the exposed url should be /apply/

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you will need `[R=301,L]`to do a redirect properly.  Apache2 by default will use a 302 redirect so if it is a permanent redirect you should force R=301, as you noted.  The documentation for [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) is unclear if `[L]` alone will always perform a 301 redirect.  Be safe, tell apache exactly what to do :-).